# What's better to use? SFML functions or OpenGL functions?

Tags: opengl, sfml

I'm finding many similar functions in SFML and OpenGL, such as loading textures, shaders, sprites, shapes etc...
But i'm wondering: what's better to use?
Is there actually a difference? Are SFML functions / objects more user friendly but slower and OpenGL functions more low level but faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. Short answer is that OpenGL gives you more control and is more centralized for graphics, SFML can do more stuff without outside libraries. There isn't a "better" one.

SFML gives access to the PC's audio, graphics, network, system and window modules.
OpenGL is very good for writing custom 2D or 3D rendering applications, it accesses with the OS's internal graphics functions.

SFML uses OpenGL under the hood and the main difference is that in OpenGL you will be writing your own renderer, 2D or 3D, from scratch. SFML it easier to use because you have do less yourself.

As for performance, i don't have any benchmarks but if you want to write a game engine then OpenGL gives alot more control thus it can achieve greater performance, especially for 3D. SFML will be sufficient for small games and applications.

As i said, it depends on what you want to do. I recommend reading more about the two.

Comment: thank you very much. i studied sfml a bit and i saw many functions were just simplifying OpenGL functions, so i was a bit confused at first. Your answer was very clear, thank you again!